# Gravity Forms are giving me a 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, gravity-forms-plugin

I have been trying to update a Gravity Form and it is giving me a 404 error everytime I try to update it. I have even tried to press update when making no changes, same error.

Does anybody know why a gravity form may give 404 errors on update?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the form you are trying to update has left the building. 
Have you tried building a new form or looking at your DB to see if the form information is accurate? Sometimes a server timeout will cause information to be dropped in the DB and you system won't know it to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your form settings, and try turning of some validations. Maybe your form Require user to be logged in or your security configuration is blocking your access.